# Sort array by comparing string value in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of custom objects. Objects contain status : paid or unpaid. 
I want to sort array like :
On first click, sort array to display paid records first and then unpaid records.
On second click, sort array to show unpaid records and then paid records.

Any help ?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try below like statement:

```
NSSortDescriptor *Sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"yourfield" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:Sorter]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as :

```
- (IBAction)sort:(id)sender {
    static BOOL isPaidFirst=YES;

    NSSortDescriptor *Sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"isPaid"
                                                             ascending:!isPaidFirst
                                                              selector:@selector(compare:)];
    [self.array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:Sorter]];

    isPaidFirst=!isPaidFirst;


    for (MyObject *obj in self.array) {
        NSLog(@"-->%@, %ld, %d",obj.courseName, obj.totalFee, obj.isPaid);
    }
    NSLog(@"------------------");

}
```

Here MyObject is as :

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property(strong)NSString *courseName;
@property NSInteger totalFee;
@property BOOL isPaid;

@end
```